# Cannot Open Email Sign In Links from Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am having trouble using the firebase auth emulator with (passwordless) Email Link SignIn. Everything seems to be working fine: `sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)` the Emulator shell provides me a link e.g.

```
To sign in as test@test.de, follow this link: http://localhost:9099/emulator/action?mode=signIn&lang=en&oobCode=bXfR9zhWzkvm9APe_7jsM6Ks3UTyi2gsobaW3FMrVG4HUsXXnZdMoK&apiKey=fake-api-key&continueUrl=localhost%3A3000%2FfinishSignUp%3FcartId%3D1234
```

However, when I try opening this link in the browser Chrome tries to open an Application to handle this link. Firefox says:

```
Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (http) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.You might need to install other software to open this address.
```

Am I missing something or is someone else experiencing this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and also looking for a solution.